# android hello world in idea on mac (AndroidDxRunner)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

have following error, when build Hello World android app in idea

```
Using javac 1.7.0_45 to compile java sources
Compilation completed with 9 errors and 4 warnings in 3 sec
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] Exception in thread "main"
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
Android Dex: [GPUInfo] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:115)
```

didn't find any solution yet, can someone help?

code:

```
package com.example.untitled;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code you have written to get this error, as there is nothing anyone could tell you otherwise.

Comment: I just created HelloWorld app, without any changes

Comment: I am not aware of what the HelloWorld app contains by default, post it anyways for reference.